# How to tell ivy resolving stops at the first found

Tags: ivy, artifactory

We'are using Artfactory for our Ant/Ivy resolution in Teamcity. For a virtual repository containing multiple local repos in a order, is there a way to tell Ivy to stop searching next local repository as soon as it found one? In ivy.xml file we use dynamic rev="latest.release". Some dependencies exist in multiple local repos and the first found version may not be the latest. But we do want to use the first one found.

Thanks

Comment: Try using a chain resolver: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/chain.html

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from documentation of Chain resolver:

> An attribute enable to indicate if the chain must be iterated after the first found or not (at least when asking for a latest revision). If the chain is iterated, then it's the latest among the ones found that is returned. If the chain is not iterated, then it's the first found which is returned.

Look at returnFirst attribute. True if the first found should be returned, defaults to false.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.